# Secure a string in PHP

Tags: php

What do you think it's the best method to secure a string in PHP? I speak of hiding its content and avoid malicious changes by the user, but be able to recover the information.

We can use the open_ssl functions, but I prefer using a simpler solution, more platform-compatible, quicker, and without the need of public/private keys.

For example, it can be useful for creating a custom URL that will be accessed with other device, like a QR code shown on a webpage that has to be scanned with iOS's Passbook or similar apps.

I think that this can be accomplished using some obfuscation method (like char replacement using a dictionary), and a trailing hash to ensure the data integrity, but I would like to hear your opinions.

Thank you

Comment: Ever heard of sessions?

Comment: I agree with @LucasKauffman - Don't reinvent the wheel. Sessions are wonderful for dynamic information. Are you trying to secure static text, written into your code?

Comment: I've edited my question with an example where sessions cannot be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Lucas Kauffman said: **Please use sessions for this.** Everything stored in the `$_SESSION` array is neither sent nor visible to the user.

Comment: I've edited my question with an example where sessions cannot be used

Comment: What you want may be an HMAC with a timestamp?